# magento bundled product Special prices fixed value

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

For Bundled products in Magneto the  Special price should be in % , I would like to specify special price not in percentage but a fixed value . Can any one suggest if that is possible and the easiest way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For Bundle product price is varying so you can't give fixed value. so that you need enter % of amount is discounted after selecting bundle items.